# tqdm with intervals inside larger loop

Tags: python, tqdm

I have an outer loop

```
for i in itertools.count():
```

and there are events that occur at intervals:

```
if i % log_interval == 0:
    perform_logging()
if i % save_interval == 0:
    save()
# etc.
```

I would like to use tqdm to track the progress toward the next log/save/etc.
Ideally, tqdm would print several progress bars simultaneously, a la

[image]

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
from __future__ import division, print_function
import itertools
from math import ceil
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

total = 987
log_interval = 2
save_interval = 9
with tqdm(total=total, desc="overall") as tOverall:
  with tqdm(total=ceil(total / log_interval), unit="log") as tLog:
    with tqdm(total=ceil(total / save_interval), unit="save") as tSave:
      for i in itertools.count(0, 1):
        sleep(0.01)
        if i % log_interval == 0:
          perform_logging()
          tLog.update()
        if i % save_interval == 0:
          save()
          tSave.update()
        if i + 1 == total:
          break
        tOverall.update()
print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a minor issue with your version, where the progressbar did not restart after each iteration. I also wanted `i` to increment indefinitely. This is the version I came up with:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import itertools
from math import ceil
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

total = 987
log_interval = 2
save_interval = 9

for i in itertools.count():
    if i % log_interval == 0:
        tLog = tqdm(total=ceil(total / log_interval), unit="log")
    if i % save_interval == 0:
        tSave = tqdm(total=ceil(total / save_interval), unit="save")

    # do work

    if i % log_interval == 0:
        tLog.update()
    if i % save_interval == 0:
        tSave.update()
```

print('\n')